# python - order of import for modules

Tags: python, python-import

For example there is some folder:

```
.
├── file_a.py
├── file_b
│   └── __init__.py
└── file_b.py
```

where `file_a.py` has something like:

```
from file_b import some_function
```

I know this is definitely not good practice, but what is the order of resolution behind?

i.e. How python decides which module to be imported for an "absolute import"?

Comment: The Python path?

Comment: If I had designed it, `file_b.py` would play the role that `file_b/__init__.py` currently does, and the latter would not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where (or whether) this information is in the documentation - a quick check in the [import system docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem) didn't turn it up - but [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) says the following:

> While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory
>   in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform
>     and whether the -O flag is specified. The list here is representative.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent
>     path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
>
> If the scan completes without returning a module or package, and at
>   least one directory was recorded, then a namespace package is created.

So according to PEP 420, if a package and a non-package module are found in the same directory with the same name, the package wins.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @JonKiparsky 's suggestion, I dug through importlib a bit, and finally found [`importlib._bootstrap.FileFinder.find_spec`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/069b8d20be8018fbd49ed5aaf64c4caba311e48f/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1233), which does indeed explicitly check for a directory before looking for valid files that fit the package name. Glad to see @user2357112 's answer, though, that this is supposed to be defined behavior, and isn't just happenstance.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little experiment, made `somelib.py` and `somelib/__init__.py`
Then tried the following

```
>>> from somelib import foo
in somelib/__init__.py
>>>
```

Evidently python prefers a directory-based module to a file-based one

As @scnerd points out, this could be accidental behavior, but it's what I'm seeing in the default implementation.

If you want to know how this happens, you would probably review [importlib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/importlib/__init__.py) for the gruesome details

Comment: I can't find any definition of what the "right answer" should be, though... It seems entirely possible that Pypy, Jython, IronPython, etc. might coincidentally do it differently